# How do I get MY Documents folder back under "This PC" in explorer view tree?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

Got this new computer with win 10 pro ... love it, save for one MAJOR issue. For some reason, it ONLY shows the "Onedrive" documents folder under this PC. For a minute, it had the "multiply" issue, which i've since fixed. And I don't want to "not use" onedrive, i like it. But I can't get to "my documents" anymore without having put it in "Quick Access" tree. Everytime I click on "Documents" under "This PC" it always goes straight to the folder in Onedrive, which i hate. I even tried deleting that folder in Onedrive, but it just remade itself and still is the only Documents link under This PC. It doesn't make since, all otehr shortcuts (Pictures, Music, Video) all go to the %UserProfile% location, but the local Documents folder would be completely lost if not for a shortcut I put under Quick Access. This is extremely frustrating! Please help!

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to unlink my Documents folder from my OneDrive account?](https://superuser.com/questions/1205668/how-to-unlink-my-documents-folder-from-my-onedrive-account)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click the OneDrive icon in the Notification area and click Settings. Click the Auto save tab. In Documents and Pictures, select `This PC only` for both Documents and Pictures. (REF: [Files save to OneDrive in Windows 10](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Files-save-to-OneDrive-in-Windows-10-33da0077-770c-4bda-b61e-8c8e8ca70ac7))

If that doesn't help, you may have to reset the shell folder paths in the registry, as in [Windows 10 User Shell Folders Restore Default Paths](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/windows-10-shell-folders-paths-defaults-restore/). (You need the registry fix #3, or refer to Table #2 for editing manually.)

Comment: i assume second solution requires reboot? i'll have to check later if it worked then. for now, no change

Comment: Logoff/login should reflect the changes.

Comment: nope and yes .... i had to completely unsync EVERYTHING (not just documents) and THEN apply the registry fix, and then logoff and back in, and it's finally back to working ... but now i'm afraid to turn syncing back on ...

Comment: Choosing "This PC Only" works for some, and for others running the REG fix (in addition to OneDrive settings) works. Not sure why you had to unsync all, though.

Answer (score 1):

The second solution about the registry entry change wasn't the correct fix for me as I had `%PUBLIC%\Documents` defined under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders`

Searching in RegEdit for the My Documents value of `{F42EE2D3-909F-4907-8871-4C22FC0BF756}`, I eventually found myself under the key shown below.  I believe the value after `HKEY_USERS` may differ from mine, but you should end up somewhere like what I show below.  Note there are multiple entries for the key above, so you need to get into `HKEY_USERS`.

```
\HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-1192409629-4096300566-4247849726-1001\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders
```

Under there, I found the My Documents value of `{F42EE2D3-909F-4907-8871-4C22FC0BF756}` set to this. `%USERPROFILE%\OneDrive\Documents`

I changed it to this, `%USERPROFILE%\Documents` rebooted the computer and now My Documents doesn't reference what is on one drive anymore.  This was truly an annoyance I am happy to get rid of.

Answer (score -2):

You have two "Documensts" folders. One is under "This PC" and the second is under your user. To find your user folder: "This PC" --> "Windows (C:)" --> "Users"--> open up your user documents.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.