# Win 10 Documents and Downloaded files missing

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

I'm not sure what happend, but my `Documents` and `Downloads` folder is empty. I've googled and tried every possible solution that was shown, but none of them seems to work, and I'm not sure what happened.

I've tried:

- [Registry fix mentioned here](https://superuser.com/questions/1071641/how-do-i-get-my-documents-folder-back-under-this-pc-in-explorer-view-tree)
- Tried enabling the hidden admin account and trying to look for the files (didn't work)
- Used an external file search program (search everything) to look for the files

I had files in the `%UserProfile%\Downloads` directory, but after doing a restart, that seems to have gone as well. I ran a disk check to make sure there wasn't anything wrong with my drives.

I'm at a loss at this point.

Here's what under my registry keys:

- `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders` [image]
- `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders` [image]

There is also a subdirectory called `Backup` and that has the following:

- `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders\Backup` [image]

Comment: So You can't see those files anywhere on your HDD? Try using Recuva or some similar software, and give us some feedback after that

Comment: Do you know the name of a file that was in one of the folders? If so, pop open a command prompt and run `dir /s filename.ext` from the root of the drive that your `downloads` folder exists/existed in/on.

Comment: Did you look in the Recycle Bin?

Comment: @Leshy Nope, apparently that didn't work, ran Recuva with deep scan and didn't manage to recover any files.

Comment: @spikey_richie  Did as you told, and it kept returning File not found, I tried multiple file names, luckily firefox downloads had the names kept, so I tried them all, but none worked.

Comment: @harrymc yes, that's the first place I looked.

Comment: You might have a disk cleanup job in the Task Scheduler.

Comment: @harrymc just checked, there is no such task, also checked the event viewer, I can't see anything that might have caused this.

Comment: @cyberbemon You can restore the missing files by using [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) to recover the files, _if they were deleted_.  As to what caused the issue, that's harder to determine as it likely didn't generate a log entry in Event Viewer.  Just an FYI, it's recommended to set up File History to back up every 12hrs - 24hrs to either an always-connected external drive, spare drive if a desktop PC, or a NAS.  This would at least guarantee you'll be able to restore a file in one of the 13 user data directories _(there's also other methods, such as WIM backups)_.

Comment: Also, you'll want to verify your `%UserProfile%\Documents` and `%UserProfile%\Downloads` were not set up as linked to your OneDrive.  The files should still list as placeholders if this was the case, but just to rule this out, login to your OneDrive account online and verify the files aren't in your OneDrive's Documents and Downloads directory.

Comment: Another reason I never keep important files in any user directory.

Comment: Did you computer update recently? Not sure if this is still possible, but there was an update quite recently which deleted the "quick access" folders.

Comment: @GašperČefarin yup, it did update on the 17th and I only noticed the issue, yesterday.

Comment: @Moab Wouldn't a more effective strategy be to set up backups via File History, `DISM`, or otherwise?